# Firebase "Invalid data, couldn't parse JSON object...."

Tags: json, parse-platform, firebase

I'm trying to make a POST request from Parse to Firebase, using Parse Cloud Code and Firebase's REST API.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createChatRoom", function(request, response) {

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://myapp.firebaseIO.com/' + '.json',
    method: 'PUT',
    body: {"hi": "hello"}
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
      response.success("Successfully posted hello!");
  },function(httpResponse) {
      response.error("failed to post hello" + httpResponse.text)
  })
})
```

However, this code makes Firebase respond with the following error:

```
"Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."
```

I have tried a multitude of combinations for `body`, including variations of apostrophes, integers, and removing brackets altogether.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question:

JSON for Firebase must be wrapped in single quotes `'`:

`body: '{"hi": "hello"}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use like this `body: JSON.stringify({"hi": "hello"})`