# Error while issuing REST put request to Google Firebase

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a PUT to my Firebase database.

I am using Advanced REST Client add-on in Chrome to issue a PUT request.

[image]

For some reason I am getting the following error

```
{
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."
}
```

I have tried both of them.

```
'"11": { "name": "Alan Turing", "birthday": "June 23, 1912" }'

'{"11": { "name": "Alan Turing", "birthday": "June 23, 1912" }}'
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: You need to post the JSON object as a string, so wrapped in single quotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683757/firebase-invalid-data-couldnt-parse-json-object and possible more of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D++couldn%27t+parse+JSON+object

Comment: When entering "Raw payload" for the Advanced Rest Client, don't put quotes around the JSON.  For your example, enter this: `{"11": { "name": "Alan Turing", "birthday": "June 23, 1912" }}`